# Parse - linking a PFUser to an email address and password

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

OK, I'm using Parse for an app.

I currently have a Facebook login but we will also be offering Twitter and Email/Password login.

I need to make sure that whichever way the user decides to login/sign up they can link everything together so they only have one account.

I know how to link the current user to a Facebook or Twitter account...

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
    }
}];
```

But there doesn't seem to be any information on linking the other way around.

i.e. if the user logs in with Facebook. Then how can I link that account with a email/password combo for log in?

Something like

```
[[PFUser currentUser] linkWithEmail:@"blah" password:@"blah" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Woohoo!");
    }
}];
```

Comment: This is really a workflow issue, and one that happens only the first time a user signs up. If they use FB, then retrieve the email from the FBGraphUser and save it to your PFUser. As for password, you won't have access to it, nor is it a given that it will be the same for email/password login or Twitter, so make one up and store it along with the email address both in the PFUser and in the Keychain. Each subsequent launch of your app, just authenticate PFUser with the Token (if one exists) or from keychain info. Keychain info persists even if app is deleted, so check that on first install.

Comment: @MDB983 just got back to this and starting to try and implement it. What I'd like is for the user to be able to log in from any device. What would happen if they log in on their iPhone with a Facebook account and then later log in on their iPad with an email/password account. I'd like them to be linked so that the email.password logs into the same account.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible as you can't guarantee that the email address associated with FB will be the same one they will use to sign in. Also, authenticating via FB doesn't give you access to the password. So unless you ask for both a FB and email/password combo, there are no certainties. The only alternative i can think of is to store encrypted credentials or token on iCloud.

Comment: @MDB983 Yeah, that's what I thought. However, thinking about it, I think I'm over thinking the potential problems when users log in. It is highly likely that they will only ever log/sign in once ever for the app. If they choose to sign up with email/password then I can link FB and Twitter. However, if they sign up with FB then I can just connect Twitter and forget username/password. (and vice versa).

Comment: One thing i will say is that i've found people prefer using email/password initially and then authenticating via FB/Twitter once they've had a look around and trust the app or really want the added feature that 'Friends list" gives them. Also, keep in mind, if this is a Rev. 1 app, you can change it later, once you can establish user patterns.